# Почему slick slider работает не исправно?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider-slick.js

При наличии в HTML трех слайдов он показывает их 7 хотя всего их 3, а остальные 4 с классом клон. Задал родителя в файле js (перед этим подключив как сам слайдер так и jQuery) самих item'ов надеясь что слайдер будет работать но все слайды выстроились в колонку и переключаются как один. Заранее спасибо https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/419b83a8-da81-4aa5-b561-741e33857a5d

Answer (score 0):

$('slick__list').slick({
dots: true,
infinite: true,
speed: 500,
fade: true,
cssEase: 'linear'
});

Попробуйте так

Comment: Не работает это не помогает